# Show all dates even those with zero data in it in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

My following query shows the date and the count of the emails found on each day (last 2 days)

My problem is that if no emails are found today, the today date will not be displayed on the output. (if yesterday has emails, it will show only 1 row with yesterday date and email).

How can I edit my query to always show 2 rows, today and yesterday, date and number of emails even zero?

```
SELECT maildate, 
       COUNT(*) AS totalEmails 
FROM   emails 
WHERE  maildate >= Date_add(Curdate(), interval - 2 DAY) 
       AND company_id = 1 
GROUP  BY DATE(maildate) 
ORDER  BY maildate desc
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display (like the missing dates issue) in application code

Comment: Do you only want an email count for today and yesterday?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes. but even if there are no rows in emails table, or no rows that meet the query, the output must have today and yesterday as 0

Answer (score 0):

There are many tricks to creating a list of dates (or numeric sequences similarly).  The one I like to use with MySQL is using @sqlvariables.  I will typically start with a baseline value such as your date -2 days.  I will do a cross-join to any other table in the database that has at least as many records as you expect in your output... Say 30 days, or a whole year 366 days, or longer.  The inner sql variable prep will keep increasing itself by whatever increment (you could even do date ranges such as begin/end of a week, month, etc).  Now you have your table of all possible dates you are looking to fill.

Now, I do a secondary query by the value -- in this case your email date and apply the group by.  Using the where clause in this query will make IT faster since it can utilize the date on its query result set before returning for the LEFT-JOIN to the date range result set.

Now, your simple left-join gets both parts of all dates to be included and those corresponding counts that do exist.

Note the table alias "AnyTableWithAtLeast3RecordInIt" in the "JustDates" query could in-fact be your "emails" table.  Since we don't care about any criteria except a record exists, and we are applying a limit of 30 days in my example, it will be instantaneous.

```
select 
      JustDates.DateToInclude,
      coalesce( SumCnts.TotalEmails, 0 ) TotalEmails
   from
      ( select
              @myDate := DATE_ADD( @myDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY ) as DateToInclude
           from
              ( select @myDate := Date_add(Curdate(), interval - 2 DAY) ) as SQLVars,
              AnyTableWithAtLeast3RecordInIt
           limit 30 ) JustDates
      left join 
      ( select
              maildate, 
              COUNT(*) AS totalEmails 
           FROM 
              emails 
           WHERE  
                  maildate >= Date_add(Curdate(), interval - 2 DAY) 
              AND company_id = 1 
           GROUP BY 
              DATE(maildate) ) SumCnts
         ON JustDates.DateToInclude = SumCnts.MailDate
```

Now, judging by your query, but unclarified request... Your emails table CAN HAVE FUTURE DATES?  Is that correct?  Such as a Dr. Office and appointments are for the future and you want to get emails out for a given range.  This is what I was inferring and hence had my limit to only go out 30 days...  If you need longer, just extend the LIMIT clause.

Comment: Hi thank you for this, it works. However, I didn't really understand why the table must have at least rows. There will be sometimes that the email table will have 0 rows in it.

Comment: In the case that the table has zero in it, it does not return any results, but is mandatory to always have the today and yesterday date, even with 0

Comment: The example using the emails table was just that... the "AnyTableWithAtLeast3RecordInIt" could be ANY table in your database that has at least as many records as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table that contains all dates in the needed range. If its only about today and yesterday, you can easily create it as a subquery (derived table).

```
SELECT Curdate() as maildate
UNION ALL
SELECT Curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

http://rextester.com/ALH50651

Now you can LEFT JOIN your table and count the rows:

```
SELECT sub.maildate, 
       COUNT(m.maildate) AS totalEmails
FROM (
    SELECT Curdate() as maildate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
) sub
LEFT JOIN emails m 
  ON  DATE(m.maildate) = sub.maildate
  AND m.company_id = 1 
GROUP BY sub.maildate
ORDER BY sub.maildate desc
```